# Docker is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have the following .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: docker:latest

variables:
 DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

services:
 - docker:dind

before_script:
 - docker info

stages:
 - deploy

step-deploy-dev:
 stage: deploy
 script:
  - echo build and deploy
  - docker build -t myimage myproject/.
  - echo finished build and deploy..
 environment: master
```

And sometimes (I can't identify the reason) I get the following error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.8.0 (079aad9e)
  on My-CI de8391de
Using Shell executor...
Running on DEVServer01...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at e5f12f9 Update .gitlab-ci.yml
From http://gitlab.ourinternalserver.nl/my/myproject
   e5f12f9..3b46be8  master     -> origin/master
Checking out 3b46be8a as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ docker info
'docker' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 9009
```

Comment: `sometimes` ? do you have other deployment steps / stages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case where you are seeing this error your job is running on a runner that is configured with the wrong executor. Your job needs a runner using the docker executor.

You can see in the output it says:

```
Using Shell executor...
```

It should say

```
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
```

You can tag the job and docker runners to ensure the jobs are only run on the required runners.
When you register the runner specify tags like "docker" and then in the job configuration add the tags attribute:

```
step-deploy-dev:
 stage: deploy
 script:
  - echo build and deploy
  - docker build -t myimage myproject/.
  - echo finished build and deploy..
 environment: master
 tags:
  - docker
```